# Postfix with sendgrid SMTP Relay "Reply To E-Mail"

Tags: email, sendgrid, postfix-mta

I have Postfix set up to send emails through sendgrip SMTP Relay. 
This works well with one exception.

When the person receives the email and tries to reply back to it, There email client tries to reply to them instead of.

Is there away to tell Postfix and/or sendgrid what the reply to email is?

Comment: Just add a `Reply-To:` header to your emails.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but is there away to do it on the .cf files so that any email account on my server will get the correct headers? Also if I do it in the email client providing a reply to header on my cellphone isn’t an option. This simply add reply-to: header isn’t a solution